# Ionic VueJS Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: enteringEl is undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm having this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: enteringEl is undefined` show up in console when I use `router.push` in Ionic to go from the home view to the profile view (for editing profile and what not)

I have already modified the templates and added `ion-page` as a wrapper to make sure it's not that, I can't quite understand what's going on. Home page loads just fine, but the other weird thing is when I go to the account page it straight up has no content on the page. I'm not sure what to do with that either as it's very hard to debug this and Google is showing me very few results.

Home Page (redirected from)

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-content>
      <HomeHero />
      <HomeTournament />
      <HomeLivestreams />
      <HomeMusic />
      <HomeCTA />
      <HomeFooter />
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { IonContent, IonPage } from "@ionic/vue";
import HomeHero from "@/components/HomeHero.vue";
import HomeTournament from "@/components/HomeTournament.vue";
import HomeLivestreams from "@/components/HomeLivestreams.vue";
import HomeMusic from "@/components/HomeMusic.vue";
import HomeCTA from "@/components/HomeCTA.vue";
import HomeFooter from "@/components/HomeFooter.vue";
</script>
```

My AccountPage (that it gets redirected to)

```
<template>
  <ion-page class="account">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="12" size-md="6">
            <ion-card>
              <ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-title>Account Info</ion-card-title>
              </ion-card-header>
              <ion-card-content>
                <ion-list>
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-input
                      type="text"
                      label="Username"
                      labelPlacement="stacked"
                      :value="authVars.name"
                    ></ion-input>
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-input
                      type="text"
                      label="Email"
                      labelPlaement="stacked"
                      :value="authVars.email"
                    ></ion-input>
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-label position="stacked">Gender</ion-label>
                    <!-- MARK// ADD GENDER SELECT HERE -->
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-input
                      type="text"
                      label="First Name"
                      labelPlaement="stacked"
                      :value="firstName"
                    ></ion-input>
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-input
                      type="text"
                      label="Last Name"
                      labelPlaement="stacked"
                      :value="lastName"
                    ></ion-input>
                  </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
              </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

```
// Login to be redirected to account page
const submitLogin = async () => {
  const isFormCorrect = await login$v.value.$validate();
  if (!isFormCorrect) return;
  console.log("Login Submitted with details: ", logInput.value);
  const accountLogged = await auth.Login(
    logInput.value.email,
    logInput.value.password
  );
  if (accountLogged.type === "success") {
    const navResult = await router.push("/account");
    if (navResult) {
      // Navigation failed
      console.log("Navigation failed to account page");
    } else {
      console.log("Navigation to account page successful");
    }
  }
};
// index.ts for router
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "@ionic/vue-router";
import { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
import HomePage from "../views/HomePage.vue";
// import AccountPage from "../views/AccountPage.vue";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: HomePage,
  },
  {
    path: "/account",
    name: "My Account",
    component: () => import("@/views/AccountPage.vue"),
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "@ionic/vue-router";
import { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
import HomePage from "../views/HomePage.vue";
// import AccountPage from "../views/AccountPage.vue";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: HomePage,
  },
  {
    path: "/account",
    name: "My Account",
    component: () => import("@/views/AccountPage.vue"),
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

What I don't understand is how my app is *supposed* to be laid out. Meaning do I need another `ion-router-outlet`? this is my App.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <AppNavDrawer />
    <AppBar />
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" />
  </ion-app>
</template>
```

Comment: I've created a GitHub for the issue https://github.com/ZachHandley/ionic-router-bug

Answer (score -1):

**First check import of all components from "@ionic/vue" then register those components in correct way inside your component.**